# Set Position of a Sprite in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, sprite

I want to set the position of a Sprite via Script but i cant use

`gameObj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);`

somehow.

it gives me the error "Sprite does not contain a definition for transform and no accesible extension method transform accepting a first argument of type Sprie could be found..."

Comment: Please add a complete code example. Your provided snippet is too little to give an answer. There are various types of "Sprites" used in Unity. Do you mean a `SpriteRenderer` or an `Image` which has the property `Image.sprite` of type `Sprite`?

Comment: Gameobject can add some Compoent , like Image , Image need sprite to show that , So you just moving gameobject well. Sprite is a resrouce not a "Gameobject" you can not moving a resource right?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a game object's position is the same as setting the sprite positions. 
(Included the fact that the sprite is a component of the game object)

```
// Moves the entire gameobject. (Aka moving the 'sprite' in the gameobject along with it)    
gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

Your error occured due to the fact that `gameObj` is a type `Sprite`, and `Sprite` don't have transforms. Its game objects that have it.

#### Edit

If you wanted to move the 'sprite' of a game-object only, make a child gameobject that hosts the sprite-renderer instead, and move the child by itself, like so:

[image: Image of the gameobjects]

And your inspector for `ObjectWithSprite` should look similar to:
[image: Image of inspector for ObjectWithSprite]

Of course, replacing `MovingGameObject` script with your intended script that will control the movement of the sprite of the gameobject:

```
public class MovingGameObject : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        // Or some other location;
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do i do that? Im very new to unity ^^ Id be very thankful!

Comment: @KamilJu edited my answer, it should show you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `gameObj` is a **sprite** not **GameObject**, if you want to handle the gameObject

You can use public variable to assign the gameObject of sprite in **Inspector**

```
public GameObject gameObj;
```

and your method to set position works now.

```
gameObj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

if you want to access the properties of sprite, you can use [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

```
Debug.Log(gameObj.GetComponent<Sprite>().pivot);
```

Maybe you should also check [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html)